# What are the most common compounds used today in CMOS IC pn junctions?

Tags: integrated-circuit, design, cmos

Many many moons ago I was using germanium-based transistors but I know we have been able to exponentially speed up switching response times with newer doping compounds.

I believe newer IC’s also incorporate MOSFETs, those compounds are also requested.

In modern CMOS integrated circuits, what are the most common base and doping compounds or elements used to achieve the best performance?

Comment: I think you are looking for silicon, arsenic, and phosphorus. Germanium is not a dopant, it is the underlying semiconductor.

Comment: Dopant compounds are mostly not responsible for speed improvements.

Comment: speed mostly comes from extremely small implants (width and depth) that minimize the # of electrons needed to charge up a node and then discharge it;